# Neovim multiple code suggestion for single code file like html,css,js in single file, either .html or .js

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, neovim, neovim-plugin

I have lsp installed for html, css, js, ts, c++ and more in neovim. I get all the suggestions and autofill. But What I want is when I write a script in   tag inside the html file. I keep getting html suggestions and no js suggestion. even while writing css inside  tag in html file. I keep getting html suggestions only because the html lsp is activated. Not only this, Sometimes I need to write css, html inside js code. I only get js suggestion and autofill for js code and not for html,css. Apart from this neovim does everything well than other editors like vscode. Just came from vscode and loving neovim, But I found this feature is not working, What else do i need to do? Any Help is appreciated.

What is want is getting all code suggestions for html, css, js in both .html file and .js file while writing code inside their specific tags in neovim.

Comment: IMHO, that wouldn't be neovim functionality. It is the responsibility of the language server.

Comment: How can I make it work? Any suggestions / solutions?

Comment: Implement your language server with such capabilities.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I'll have a try. I am a newbie at such configuration, I'm still learning these stuffs.

Comment: This is a complicated task to do, start by reading some info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol)

Comment: Thanks. I'll read it. I want to figure out how it works on other ide. So, If its configurable. I'd love to apply on neovim, which makes me complete. even without it neovim is rocking.